# How to hide keypad in android device in mobile browser using appium & selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium, appium

How to hide keypad in android device in mobile browser using `appium & selenium` with `java`.
I tried:

`driver.hideKeyboard()`

method which is working good in app but not in browser.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**Why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think I had similar issue in one of projects, but can't quite get which and what solution I've used, but I have some general idea. Try some of examples bellow.

Comment: I have used driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK); for AndroidDriver

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

or

```
driver.sendKeyEvent(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);
```

or

```
driver.navigate.back()
```

some of this 3 solutions should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
capabilities.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
capabilities.setCapability("resetKeyboard", true);
```

Set the above 2 capabilities. Appium will use its own keyboard and there won't be any keyboard displayed on screen. resetKeyboard will ensure that your old default keyboard is set when the session ends.